# How to make a rectangles in this order?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make a rectangles in this order at flutter ?

[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYbag.jpg)

Comment: That's easy you can make a container first for the first box and then take a column and add row in it to make the 2 containers and repeat that row again for the below 2 boxes and that will do the work. For spacing you can add sizedboxes however you like

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

[image: DartPad]

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to wrap a container and two rows in a column.

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.green
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.yellow
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.orange
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be something like this:

```
  Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text('Top Rectangle'),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Text('Row 1 - Col 1'),),
            Expanded(child: Text('Row 1 - Col 2'),),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Text('Row 2 - Col 1'),),
            Expanded(child: Text('Row 2 - Col 2'),),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Or this:

```
   Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text('Top Rectangle'),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 400,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text('Row 1 - Col 1'),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text('Row 1 - Col 2'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text('Row 2 - Col 1'),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text('Row 2 - Col 2'),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

- It's not a good idea to have a bunch of `Expanded` widgets in a parent widget, you should have `Containers` or similar widgets and give them fixed or dynamically calculated heights, then you can have an `Expanded` which gets all remaining space